# Paypal payment pro PayPal express order not sending confirmation email in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I have a very long standing issue with PayPal Payments Pro in magento. If a customer places an order using PayPal express they don't receive the order email. If a customer pays with card they get it with no problems.

I have spent a lot of time investigating this with no joy at all. I am wondering if other people have had the same issue and if anyone has managed to solve it. I am running magento community 1.9.2.

The IPN seems to be working properly, and there are no orders in the email que.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*PayPal Payment Pro not send confirmation email facility.But you can achieve it by creating observer after payment receive.*

> > You may use event **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**. This can be used if your order success.
> >
> > There is another event **sales_order_payment_pay**. This can be used if your order success. It may also use in your case.
>
> **1 )** Make custom **config.xml** for call observer file
>
> > > The **config.xml** defines your module and declares your event listener for a given event (**checkout_onepage_controller_success_action** is sent when onepage checkout process is complete, **sales_order_payment_pay** is sent when the payment has been confirmed).

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>            
            <sales_order_payment_pay>
                <observers>
                    <Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customFunction</method>
                    </Namespace_Modulename_Customevent>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_pay>
        </events>
    </frontend>    
</config>
```

> **2 )** create **observer.php** file inside your module/Model directory and paste this code

```
<?php
  class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

         $order_id = $observer->getData('order_ids');
         $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
         //your code here


    }        

}
```

Hope It's helpful for you.